# Passing borrowing reference as not borrowing

Tags: rust

```rust
fn count_occur(v: &Vec<i32>, val: i32) -> usize {
    0
}

fn main() -> () {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    for &item in &v1 {
        let v2 = count_occur(&v1, item);
        println!("{}", v2);
    }
}
```

`item` is a not mutable borrowing reference. Why does the compiler accept that code? After all, `count_occur` accepts **not** borrowing reference to `i32`?

Comment: Because it implements the [Copy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait. It is copied on the fly.